# Permission Error when trying to create PDF with ReportLab on an iOS Device

Tags: python, ios, xcode, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to create an iOS app that generates a PDF and saves it the user's phone (possibly to the Files app or just displays it to them with an option to save). When I run my app on my computer, the PDF is created and saved on my computer, but I get a Permission Error when running it on my phone in Xcode. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do on a phone? Should I use a different module rather that ReportLab? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried running the app on simulator iOS devices with no luck (no file seems to be created at all). But, on a real phone, the app crashes when I try to save the PDF.

Here's the code where the PDF is saved:

```py
c = canvas.Canvas(filename)
c.setFontSize(36)
c.drawCentredString(306,750,name)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Here's the error message I get in Xcode when I try to save

`PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'test.pdf'`

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: Reportlab is a python module - the app I created is made with python

Comment: Hi OP, have you been able to figure out anything about this? I am running into a similar problem. It appears that the file system on the phone differs from what is available when running on the computer; I speculate that ReportLab is making some kind of assumption about the file system which doesn't hold when running on the phone. If you have figured out anything, I would be interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the pdf is open on your phone? Having a file open and then trying to write to it with a python program can trigger an error.

I get a permission error with excel if the file is open, which is what makes me think this.

Comment: The PDF isn't open on my phone when I run it. The PDF is supposed to be created in the app then saved to the user's device